ColdFusion (2018): how to use SFTP connection
Trying to connect to SFTP directory using <cfftp>, but so far unsuccessful.
<cfset FTP_server="ftp.mysite.com">
<cfset FTP_site="NS">
<cfset FTP_user="user">
<cfset FTP_pwd="pwd">
<cfset FTP_key="AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAA">

<cfftp 
    action="OPEN" 
    server="#FTP_server#" 
    connection="#FTP_site#"
    username="#FTP_user#" 
    password="#FTP_pwd#"
    secure="yes"
    <!--- key="#FTP_key#" --->
    stopOnError = "Yes">

<cfdump var ="#FTP_site#"><cfabort>


I can connect w/out issues using FileZilla. however.
If I add "key", then I get different error:

What am I missing?

In your second error, "key" isn't allowed with the other attributes. It's an invalid combination. Could it be that the foreign host needs to whitelist your CF server?

I got it to connect, but for some reason directory listing is not displayed.


There are no errors? Could the directory be empty?

No errors. I can clearly see 11 directories

We have two options for this: key-based or password-based. In this case, I've used the password-based approach. In order to accomplish this, you should include 'passive' with a value of 'yes' and set 'secure' to 'no' within the cfftp tag. Also we have to use an 'LISTDIR' action to display the list of directory.
<cfset FTP_server = "xyz.com">
<cfset FTP_site = "NS">
<cfset FTP_user = "mysite.com">
<cfset FTP_pwd = "myftppassword">
<cfset FTP_key="AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAA">

<cfftp 
    action="OPEN" 
    server="#FTP_server#" 
    connection="My_FTP_Connection" 
    username="#FTP_user#" 
    password="#FTP_pwd#" 
    passive="yes" 
    secure="no" 
    stopOnError="Yes">

<cfftp action="LISTDIR" 
    name="RemoteDirectoryContents" 
    connection="My_FTP_Connection" 
    directory="/" 
    stopOnError="Yes">

<cfftp action="close" connection="My_FTP_Connection">
<cfdump var="#RemoteDirectoryContents#">


I hope it will helps for you. Thanks.
